# Pattern printing in Swift

Tags: swift

Can someone please help me printing this pattern in Swift....i am trying but its not working.

```
N=5                                N=4
15                                 10   
14   7                             9   4
13   8   6                         8   5   3
12   9   5  2                      7   6   2   1
11   10  4  3  1
```

i tried writing this code

```swift
// for the first pattern N=5
for n in 15..1, n-- {
    for  j in 1..5, j++ {
        print( j, n-1)
    }
    print(separator : " " )
}

// for the second pattern N=4
for n in 10..1, n-- {
    for j in 1..4, j++ {
        print( j, terminator : " ")
    }
    print(separartor : " ")
}
```

Comment: Pattern seems to be a triangle that goes in decending order from the first column, and alternating acending columns, where N is the number of rows and columns. So with n = 5, first column has 5 rows. Starts at 15, decends downward, second row start at the bottom, and decends upward, third row starts at the top, decends downward, etc.

Comment: that i understood my friend, i have a hard time writing the logic for the same.

Comment: Why have you hardcoded 15 and 10, isn’t it part of the exercise to calculate those numbers?

Comment: yes sir, i am trying to correct my mistake, i am new to this development field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the result is ultimately just a collection of strings (the stringified values of a row), I would suggest using an array of strings which are populated by stepping up and down the rows and columns. This way, the value can simply be decremented with each step:

```swift
func printPattern(n: Int) {
    var rowVals: [String] = .init(repeating: "", count: n)
    var row = 0
    var col = 0
    var val = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
    while val > 0 {
        while row < n {
            rowVals[row] += (col > 0 ? "\t\(val)" : "\(val)")
            val -= 1
            row += 1
        }
        col += 1
        while row > col {
            row -= 1
            rowVals[row] += "\t\(val)"
            val -= 1
        }
        row += 1
        col += 1
    }
    for vals in rowVals {
        print(vals)
    }
}

printPattern(n: 5)
print()
printPattern(n: 4)
```

This prints the following:

```
15
14  7
13  8   6
12  9   5   2
11  10  4   3   1

10
9   4
8   5   3
7   6   2   1
```

Comment: Works like a charm my friend!

Comment: Thanks a Ton, i will surely look at it and learn

Comment: @AbhishekGautam the way to express your thanks is to _accept_ the answer (checkmark).

Comment: @AbhishekGautam Glad to have been able to help. I edited the answer and scrapped the first solution, the second approach is simpler so I didn't think the other was needed any more. BTW, if the answer helped, you are welcome to accept it (by tapping the checkmark) and/or give it an upvote ;)

Answer (score -3):

Please try this

```
func printPattern(n: Int) {
    for i in 1...n {
        for j in n...1 {
            if i == j {
                print("15", terminator: " ")
            } else if i > j {
                print("\(15 - (i - j) * 2)", terminator: " ")
            } else {
                print("\(15 + (j - i) * 2)", terminator: " ")
            }
        }
        print()
    }
}

printPattern(n: 5)
printPattern(n: 4)
```

This code will print the following output:

```
15 10
14 7 9
13 8 6 8
12 9 5 3
11 10 4 2
15 10 4 3
14 7 6 2 1
```

Comment: i ran your code and it says "Range requires lowerBound <= upperBound" in the 3rd line

Comment: N=5                                N=4
15                                 10   
14   7                            9    4
13   8   6                       8     5   3
12   9   5  2                   7    6    2    1
11  10  4  3  1

Comment: i corrected that error , but still the output which i want is not printing

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**